# How to set an offset of ImageView between the animation and its repeat in TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

I have an ImageView, it is in the middle of the screen. I created a TranslateAnimation to move ot to the right edge of the screen with this code:

```
      logoAnimationLeft2Right = new TranslateAnimation(0, screenWidth/2+imageWidth, 0, 0);
      logoAnimationLeft2Right.setDuration(500);
      logoAnimationLeft2Right.setFillAfter(false);
      logoAnimationLeft2Right.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
      logoAnimationLeft2Right.setRepeatCount(1);
```

Using this, my ImageView goes off to the right edge and the rolls back from the right to the center. I'd like to create an offset to make the ImageView to come back on the LEFT side of the screen and go back to the center (appearing to go "around" the center).

What should I do to make this offset between the animation and its reversed repeat?

Comment: you can play with a custom Interpolator, try it

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I skip this time, my animation is quite simple but I'll eventually try it :)

Comment: just create a TranslateAnimarion like you did but without any reapiting stuff and set an interpolator like Math.sin(input * 2 * Math.PI), thats all, no reapiting no complex animation sets, simple, plain, easy

Answer (score 1):

Use `AnimationSet`, contains the animation to the right and the animation to the left side, play then sequentailly and repeatly.

Comment: Good idea, I created an AnimationSet and set the startOffset of the second animation. However, they are played reversed: the delayed animation starts first then the other one. How can I change it?

Comment: So strange? try to debug and check. Also you could use `Animator/AnimatorSet` to implement. could you paste you code ?

Comment: Here is the current code that plays the animation:   logoAnimationLeft2Right = new TranslateAnimation(0, width / 2 + imageWidth, 0, 0);
      logoAnimationLeft2Right.setDuration(500);

      logoAnimationLeft2Right2 = new TranslateAnimation(0 - width / 2 - imageWidth, 0, 0, 0);
      logoAnimationLeft2Right2.setStartOffset(500);
      logoAnimationLeft2Right2.setDuration(500);
      setLeft2Right.addAnimation(logoAnimationLeft2Right);
      setLeft2Right.addAnimation(logoAnimationLeft2Right2);

Comment: I changed to XML but the result is the same: it first sarts from left to middle then middle to right. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
  <translate
      android:fromXDelta="0"
      android:toXDelta="100%p"
      android:duration="500"/>
  <translate
      android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
      android:toXDelta="0"
      android:duration="500"
      android:startOffset="550"/>
</set>